# Laravel - Transponer de filas a columnass

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

tengo una consulta SQL tipo esta, que me devuelve un resultado como el que muestro en la captura.

```
   $calls = DB::select('SELECT c.title,c.text,a.user_id, d.name, d.email, b.value, b.created_at
            FROM ....
            where e.uuid = :uuid ', ['uuid' => $uuid]);
```

**Resultados SQL**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta información deseo mostrarla en un "datatable" agrupando por el campo "**name**" + **email** por lo que el resultado deseado seria este

**Resultado deseado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podeis ver, quiero agrupar el resultado obtenido por "cliente" lo que seria el campo "name" + "email"

He probado a hacerlo desde mysql sin éxito, y luego a partir de la collection que me devuelve la consulta intentar hacerlo tampoco sin éxito.

Cualquier sugerencia será bien agradecida.

Gracias,

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres lograr, había entendido que quieres agruparlo, y se lograba con `order by` tal y como te respondieron pero si no es lo que buscas, entonces deberías aclarar mejor tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

nose si responde a lo que deseas hacer pero podrías hacer un order by por nombre y luego por email. Resultando:

```
 $calls = DB::select('SELECT c.title,c.text,a.user_id, d.name, d.email, b.value, b.created_at
            FROM ....
            where e.uuid = :uuid order by d.name, d.email', ['uuid' => $uuid])
;
```

Un saludo.

Comment: No, lo que necesito es transponer filas a columnas